# How to send alt + f7 key from autokey

Tags: autokey

I want to send `alt+f7` keys from `autokey`. Following are the code samples which I tried:

- `keyboard.send_keys("<alt>+<f7>")`
- `keyboard.send_key("<alt>+<f7>")`
- `keyboard.fake_keypress("<alt>+<f7>")`

I tried with `repeat=1` also. It doesn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Videonauth I don't know how I could clarify more? I want to send `alt+f7` keys from `autokey`. I have also included the code samples which I tried.

Comment: Well i did the editing for you

Comment: @Videonauth thanks. But I was corrected one time on stack overflow for superfluous information. `autokey` mentioned in title as well as tag. Is the etiquette different here?

Comment: Well, we dont want stories about your pet and children in questions, but not everyone looks directly at the tag, so adding a little sentence about what you want to achieve and what you tried isn't superfluous. And you only had the tag which made it almost impossible to determine whats going on.

Answer (score 4):

This script worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and autokey-gtk 0.90.4:

```
keyboard.press_key('<alt>')
keyboard.fake_keypress('<f7>')
keyboard.release_key('<alt>')
```

I observe about a second delay though before the script executes. Maybe its just on my computer.

Comment: same annoying delay on my ubuntu 20

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't allow the system wide keyboard shortcuts to be emulated by autokey.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/567222)

Comment: @Videonauth I am the author. Since the comment thread in question was very long, I provided the answer here to provide visibility for others who may be facing similar issue.

Comment: @Videonauth: I disagree. A question "how can I achieve A through B?" may very well have the answer "A is unachievable through B". If you disagree with that assessment it still remains an answer as per the guidelines of AU. Wrong™ answers are still answers.

Comment: @Videonauth Relevant Meta post: [If an answer cannot possibly give you what you asked for, please consider accepting nevertheless](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15660/if-an-answer-cannot-possibly-give-you-what-you-asked-for-please-consider-accept?cb=1)

Comment: @NickWeinberg I have read and understood the comments before that, still I can't retract a review I did at that time. So this means i can delete my first comment, but the whole answer will be stuck in the review queue until its done being reviewed.

Comment: @Videonauth How frustrating : /

Answer (score 0):

Autokey scripts are plain Python files. Autokey uses Python scripting engine. So please check your script by running directly in Python and if it works there then it will work in Autokey too.

You can also try

```
keyboard.press_key("<alt>")
keyboard.send_keys("<f7>")
keyboard.release_key("<alt>")
```

Comment: You should add some delay between each keystrokes with this command:


time.sleep(0.1)